# what effect does parenthesis have when selecting a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, amazon-redshift

I have an unusual problem in Redshift (postgreSQL). It's too long to replicate here but someone on my team had code like this:

```
select (year) as year, (month) as month, (other_col) as other_col, sum(numerical_val) as num
from big_table
where (a few conditions)
group by (year), (month), (other_col)
union
select (year) as year, (month) as month, (other_col) as other_col, sum(numerical_val) as num
from big_table
where (more specific condition)
group by (year), (month), (other_col);
```

I didn't think it was necessary to have (year) as year, etc., so I removed them and did like this:

```
select year, month, other_col, sum(numerical_val) as num
from big_table
where (a few conditions)
group by year, month, other_col
union
select year, month, other_col, sum(numerical_val) as num
from big_table
where (more specific condition)
group by year, month, other_col;
```

I expected the same output but numerical_val is a fraction of a percent different. What the heck is that?

I tried several experiments and with just one query (no union), I get the same exact result using "year" compared with "(year) as year" etc. Something changes with the union.

Can you take a guess why the "(year) as year" parts would change the output in a union?

Comment: maybe query result cache? you changed the query text left it logically unchanged but the original query was probably cached

Comment: Can you please provide some sample inputs and outputs to demonstrate what you are describing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the data types of the numbers being `sum()`ed?

In particular, floating point types are *approximate*.  And further more, the order of adding them up can affect the results.  This has to do with rounding errors accumulating in different ways based on the order of the addition.

You don't provide much information so this is my best guess on why you would get similar but slightly different answers.